# Computed column formula ( yyMMdd## )

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a computed column formula that gives me this `yyMMdd##`.

I have an identity column (`DataID`) and a date column (`DataDate`).

This what I have so far.

```
(((right(CONVERT([varchar](4),datepart(year,[DataDate]),0),(2))+
right(CONVERT([varchar](4),datepart(month,[DataDate]),0),(2)))+
right(CONVERT([varchar](4),datepart(day,[DataDate]),0),(2)))+
right('00'+CONVERT([varchar](2),[DataID],0),(2)))
```

And this gives me:

```
12111201
12111202
12111303
12111304
12111405
12111406
12111407
12111508
```

What I want is:

```
12111201
12111202
12111301
12111302
12111401
12111402
12111403
12111501
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm **assuming** you want to have a sequence starting at 1 for each date - right? If not: please **explain** what you really want / need.

You won't be able to do this with a `IDENTITY` column and a computed column specification. An `IDENTITY` column returns constantly increasing numbers.

What you **could** do is not store those values on disk - but instead use CTE and the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY....)` construct to create those numbers on the fly - whenever you need to select them. Or have a job that sets those values based on such a CTE on a regular basis (e.g. once every hour or so).

That CTE might look something like this - again, **assuming** that `DataDate` is indeed of type `DATE` (and not `DATETIME` or something like that) :

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
       DataID, DataDate,
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DataDate ORDER BY DataID)
    FROM
       dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT 
    DataID, DataDate, RowNum
FROM
    CTE
```

Comment: @Lamak: true - or maybe even something else entirely - just intended to be a sample to show what's possible. Updated my response - thanks!